# Object vs function constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I want to clear up a concept. Please tell me if my understand is correct:

Many javascript build-in objects, like Object, String, Array, Date, XMLHttpRequest, we keep saying they are objects, but they are actually constructor functions, am I right?

or these two name are used interchangeably.

Thanks

Comment: Functions are Objects. ;-)

Comment: `object` doesn't really mean anything. Almost everything is an "object". Now these elements are constructors indeed, which are functions, and contains static methods such as `Array.isArray`

Comment: Oh, and *XMLHttpRequest* is a host object, so a very different animal to the other objects in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to sum it up:

- every object has a hidden `__proto__` property
- functions are objects that also have a `prototype` property
- if, for some object O and function F, `O.__proto__ == F.prototype`, we say that "O is an instance of F"
- "F object" is a way to refer to an object that is an instance of "F". For example:

> [String object: member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in String constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18)

and the same for other built-in and user-defined types. If you have

```
 function Point(x,y) { ... }
 p = new Point(10,20)
```

then "p is a Point object". In a casual conversation you're also allowed to say "p is a Point" although this isn't strictly correct.

Comment: I guess this is technically true, but I don't think it actually answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

`Object`'s prototype is the root prototype for *most* entities in JavaScript.

The items you list are all constructor functions, yes.

```
typeof Array // 'function'
```

Invoking a constructor returns an object.

```
typeof (new Array()) // 'object'
typeof (new Date()) // 'object'
```

Comment: I believe `Object.prototype` (which inherits from `null`) is the root prototype, not the constructor `Object` itself.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 you are correct; I think constructors make this much more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: "*However, the prototype of Function is Object*" nope, [*Function.prototype*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.3) is an instance of *Function*, it is *Function.prototype* that inherits from *Object.prototype* (or in your notation, you might write `Function.__prototype__ === Function.prototype` and `Function.prototype.__prototype__===Object.prototype`).

Comment: @RobG agreed; I've edited to be what I hope is the simplest possible response to OPs question. (OP isn't really asking about prototypes, but there are extensive resources here and elsewhere if and when they do.)